# Is it possible to use HttpClient cache for concurrent requests?

Tags: ehcache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using HttpClient 4.5.2 where I've setup a CachingHttpClient that uses an EhCache to save files into a persistant diskStore. This works for normal requests, that happen after the initial download has been completed.

I don't know what happens if multiple threads try to download the same file for the first time. Do I have to use a FutureRequestExecutionService, or there is a better way to achieve this? The files that the application will have to download can be huge, and I expect multiple requests for each file.

Comment: after some manual testing I think it is already working with concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a caching solution like Ehcache does not resolve the [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem).

So it depends on the way HttpClient will handle this use case.

Note that Ehcache supports a [read-through pattern](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/caching-patterns.html#read-through) which will resolve this problem by ensuring only a single requests cause the cache value to be loaded while others do wait.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question was mostly directed to the httpclient library, but I will accept it since there isn't any more activity at the moment. I can only assume that httpclient is taking advantage of the read-through pattern, since I can see it working in practice.

Comment: While I have set .maxEntriesLocalHeap(1), I can still see the heap from that cache going up every time I download a file. It can take up to 500mb for a 80mb xml file. Do you think this has something to do with the configuration of ehcache?